# How to get doc snapshot as a list

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to get the doc snapshot from fbfirestore as a list

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection("groups")
            .doc(groupId)
            .snapshots(),
```

This is the snapshot

```
Text((snapshot.data as DocumentSnapshot)['members']),
```

[image]

Comment: The members field of this document is going to show up as an array of strings, so you should write code to treat it as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this.

```
Text((snapshot.data as DocumentSnapshot)['members'][0]),
```